# Is there a limit to how many web components / custom elements you can define?

Tags: web-component

I am building a ~largish app with about ~50 components (class definitions and window.customElements.define calls). Do I need to be concerned on how many I define? Can having too much slow down the browsers Dom parsing? Is there a limit to how many I can define?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't hit limits with general DOM recommendations:

- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/dom-size
- maximum 1,500 nodes total.
- no depth greater than 32 nodes.
- no parent node with more than 60 child nodes.

#### Going extreme

Here is 5000 Custom Elements, all nested:

```js
let startTime = new Date() / 1;
let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
let nested = fragment;
let name, nr = 5000;
let done = `${nr} elements done in `;
do {
  name = "e-" + nr;
  customElements.define(name, class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.append(this.nodeName);
    }
  });
  nested = nested.appendChild(document.createElement(name));
} while (--nr);
document.body.append(done, new Date() / 1 - startTime, " milliseconds  ", fragment)
```

---

Comparing speed is a bit senseless ... my Chrome with 30+ extensions is slower than my Edge without any extensions.

#### Do think about (CSS) Selectors and Custom Elements

I did 52 [SVG playing cards](https://cardmeister.github.io)(in 16 Kb) with Autonomous elements:

```
<two-of-hearts></two-of-hearts>
<ten-of-hearts></ten-of-hearts>
<ace-of-hearts></ace-of-hearts>
...
<ace-of-spades></ace-of-spades>
```

Yeah! great Semantic HTML..

**But** you can NOT do **partial** nodeName (CSS) selectors

So in the end a **single** Autonomous Element:

`<playing-card is="ace-of-hearts"></playing-card>`

made more sense, to be able to use CSS:

```css
 [is*="hearts"]{
  border : 2px solid green;
 }
```

and JavaScript:

```
  let aces = document.querySelectorAll('[is*="ace"]');
```